# Writing to a csv after extracting data from a db, cannot modify variable with data

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, generics

```
using Dapper;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace writingCSV
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var PatientEmails = await GetPatients();
            Type myType = PatientEmails.GetType();
            Console.WriteLine(myType);
        }

        public class PatientSurvey: IDisposable
        {
            public string Location { get; set; }
            public string Email { get; set; }

            public void Dispose()
            {
                throw new NotImplementedException();
            }
        }

        static public async Task<IEnumerable<PatientSurvey>> GetPatients()
        {
            var connectionString = "SERVER INFORMATION";
            
            using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                cnn.Open();

                var patientSurveys = await cnn.QueryAsync<PatientSurvey>("STORED PROC NAME",
                                null,
                                commandTimeout: 120,
                                commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                return patientSurveys;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm attempting to write data to a CSV file from a database. I've successfully connected to the db and extracted the data into a C# object, but I cannot figure out how to modify my data so I can actually write it into the file. The `PatientEmails` variable has the data within it, but it seems like it's just an instance of the `PatientSurvey` class.

If I run my variable through a `foreach` loop, it prints out `writingCSV.Program.PatientSurvey` for each time it loops.

Comment: *If  I run my variable through a foreach loop* - you should show us the code you try; telling a story about it means it is less clear to us what you've actually done. It sounds like you've done `foreach(var v in patientEmails) Console.Write(v);` which, given the lack of an `public override string ToString` that defines how the object should be represented as a string, means you're just getting the default ToString provision which is to print the name of the type. In Python you may very well be able to print(x) and see some canned representation of x, but C# requires you to be specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problem. `GetPatients` returns an `IEnumerable` of `PatientSurvey` so indeed looping on the list just print out `writingCSV.Program.PatientSurvey`.
What would you expect?
If your goal is to print patients email then you should write something like

```
foreach (var p in patientEmails) {
   Console.WriteLine(p.Email);
}
```

Comment: thank you so much this was very helpful. I typically use Python so this is very hard for me